# Data byte offset of elements of a vector inside a struct

Tags: c++, stdvector

If I have a `struct` with members `int a, b, c;`, I can get the byte offset of each member using `offsetof(structName, member)`.

Now, if I have a `struct` with a `vector<int> { a, b, c }`, I can get the offset of the `vector` using `offsetof(structName, vectorName)`.

Knowing this, is this operation:

```cpp
offsetof(structName, vectorName) + sizeof(vector<int>) + sizeof(int)*2
```

a valid way of getting the offset of `b`?

Comment: You'll see only the maintenance data of that vector, the `data()` function can be used to access the dynamically allocated array of elements directly. For what do you need that? You shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `b` is the `vector`'s 2nd element, but `sizeof(int)*2` would return the offset of the 3rd element instead.

But more importantly, the `vector`'s element array is not stored inside the `vector` class itself, so using offsets relative to the `vector` itself will not work.  The actual array is stored elsewhere in memory, and then the `vector` contains an internal member that is a *pointer* to the array.

As such, all you really need to determine the offset of an element in the `vector`'s array is `sizeof(vector::value_type) * index` (where `index` is 1 for `b` in your example).  However, to actually access the element using that offset, you first need the pointer to the array itself.  You can use the `vector`'s `data()` method, or `operator[]`, to get that pointer, eg:

```cpp
structName *s = ...;
vector<int> *v = reinterpret_cast<vector<int>*>(
    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(s)
    + offsetof(structName, vectorName)
);
int *arr = v->data();
// or: int *arr = &(*v)[0];
size_t offset = sizeof(int) * index;
int *element = reinterpret_cast<int*>(
    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(arr)
    + offset
);
// use element as needed...
```

However, you really shouldn't use `offsetof` like this.  The above can be greatly simplified to this instead:

```cpp
structName *s = ...;
int *element = s->vectorName.data() + index;
// or: int *element = &(s->vectorName[index]);
// use element as needed...
```